# Completely inelastic collisions & center-of-mass acceleration

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, conservation-laws, acceleration, collision

The system can be isolated, or non-isolated, and comprises of, say, two carts. If these two carts undergo a completely inelastic collision, will they then accelerate together at the center of mass acceleration? Why so, or why not?

Answer (score 0):

They would never accelerate ,due to the conservation of momentum. The velocity of combined mass after the collision will always be less than the either of the initial velocity. Unless the object breaks into pieces on collision.